# is it possible to make checkout with custom variable having amount to be billed Magento

Tags: function, magento, checkout, custom-post-type

> I have create a module in which there are three options for the users to select which
>   have the different amounts
>
> and the registration form also on the same page

,

> on the basis of that the customer group is set and it got registered

, now i want to know

> is it possible to make the customer checkout with that variable amount
>   which the user has select .

Please suggest me what approach should i use or any ideas will be highly appreciate 
thanks

Comment: you want this facility for your product?

Comment: no i have custom form which have three radio buttons having different values, i just want to make the user checkout through that form value, i mean i want the value from the form should be added in cart and the user can checkout with that amount .